# Select option from dropdown menu and show data about it on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently learning html, css, javascript and I'm making a simple project where the user selects an option from the drop-down menu. There is some data about that option in an array. I would like to output that data on the same page but a bit on the right-hand side of the page.
I'm kind of stuck outputting the data associated with the option from the drop-down menu. When you select an option from drop-down menu, all the data comes out on the screen while I would like only one piece of data per drop-down option i.e. choosing Apple showing Apple data only.

Preferably not jquery just pure javascript at the moment.Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=<device-width>, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .hide{
        display: none;
    }
    .show{
        display:block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <article>
      <h1>List</h1>
      <div>
        <select name="food" id="food" onchange="changeVal()">
          <option value=""selected>Select One</option>
          <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
          <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
          <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
          <option value="All">All Food</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div id="chosenFood" class="hide">
        <h1 style = "text-align:center;">Food List</h1>
        <div id="showFoodList"></div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </main>
<script>
  function changeVal()
  {
    var f = document.getElementById("food");
    var chosenFood = f.options[f.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("chosenFood").value=chosenFood;
    document.getElementById("chosenFood").className="show";
  }
  var foodInfo = [{
    "Name" : "Apple",
    "Colour" : "Green"
  },
  {
    "Name" : "Chocolate",
    "Colour" : "Brown"
  },
  {
    "Name" : "Banana",
    "Colour" : "Yellow"
  }];
  function showFood(info)
  {
    var out="";
    for(var i=0;i<info.length;++i)
    {
      out+='<label>Name: '+info[i].Name +'<br></label>' +
      '<label>Name: '+info[i].Colour +'<br></label><br>'

    }
    document.getElementById("showFoodList").innerHTML=out;
  }
  showFood(foodInfo);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code and your explanations seem very confusing to me.
There is the need for different JS techniques, and I don't know where to start to explain my answer.
Don't hesitate to ask me anything about it!

## First version

```js
const
  foodInfo = 
    [ { Name: 'Apple',     Colour: 'Green'  } 
    , { Name: 'Chocolate', Colour: 'Brown'  } 
    , { Name: 'Banana',    Colour: 'Yellow' } 
    ] 
, selectFood = document.getElementById('food-select')
, listFood   = document.getElementById('food-list')
, DomParser  = new DOMParser()
  ;
function newItem(item)
  {
  let newItem = `
    <article class="noDisplay" data-ref="${item.Name}">
      <label> ${item.Name} </label>
      <label> ${item.Colour} </label>
    </article> `
  return (DomParser.parseFromString(newItem, 'text/html')).body.firstChild
  }
foodInfo.forEach(item=>
  {
  listFood.appendChild(newItem(item))
  selectFood.add( new Option(item.Name, item.Name))
  })
selectFood.add( new Option('All Food', 'All'))
selectFood.querySelector('option').disabled = true

const listArticles = listFood.querySelectorAll('article[data-ref]')

selectFood.onchange=()=>
  {
  let choose = selectFood.value 
  listArticles.forEach(art=>
    {
    if (choose==='All' || choose===art.dataset.ref)
      art.classList.remove('noDisplay')
    else
      art.classList.add('noDisplay')
    })
  }
```

```css
.noDisplay { display: none !important; }
#food-list { display: table; }
#food-list article { display: table-row; }
#food-list label   { display: table-cell; padding: .2em .7em; }
#food-list article:first-of-type { font-weight:bold; }
```

```html
<h3>List</h3>
<select id="food-select" >
  <option value="" selected >Select One</option>
</select> 

<h3>Food List</h3>
<div id="food-list">
  <article class="">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <label>Colour:</label>
  </article>
</div>
```

*Note :* this one use [DOMParser.parseFromString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#DOMParser.parseFromString), which I find easier to insert multiple html lines with, multiple variables, on a page.

## second version (with table)

To replace the articles and labels with a real table, here is the code.
*Note :* there is also js directs methods for tables :

- [HTMLTableElement.insertRow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)
- [HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell)

```js
const
  foodInfo = 
    [ { Name: 'Apple',     Colour: 'Green'  } 
    , { Name: 'Chocolate', Colour: 'Brown'  } 
    , { Name: 'Banana',    Colour: 'Yellow' } 
    ] 
, selectFood = document.getElementById('food-select')
, listFood_t = document.querySelector('table#food-list tbody') 
  ;
foodInfo.forEach(item=>
  {
  // table listFood elements
  let row           = listFood_t.insertRow()
  row.dataset.ref   = item.Name

  row.insertCell().textContent = item.Name
  row.insertCell().textContent = item.Colour

  // food-select
  selectFood.add( new Option(item.Name, item.Name))
  })
selectFood.add( new Option('All Food', 'All'))  // last one...
selectFood.querySelector('option').disabled = true

const tableArticles = listFood_t.querySelectorAll('tr[data-ref]')

tableArticles.forEach(el=>el.className='noDisplay') // none on start...

selectFood.onchange=()=>
  {
  let choose = selectFood.value 
  tableArticles.forEach(art=>
    {
    if (choose==='All' || choose===art.dataset.ref)
      art.classList.remove('noDisplay')
    else
      art.classList.add('noDisplay')
    })
  }
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: .7em;
  } 
caption {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight:bold;
  }
thead {
  background-color: #add8e6;
  font-weight:bold;
  }
td {
  padding: .2em .7em;
  width: 8em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  }
tbody {
  text-align: right;
  }
.noDisplay {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<h3>List</h3>
<select id="food-select" >
  <option value="" selected >Select One</option>
</select> 

<table id="food-list">
  <caption>Food List</caption>
  <thead> <tr> <td> Name </td> <td> Colour </td> </tr> </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is pretty much what i wanted, thank you very much for the help.im gonna have a look now at the implementation and learn.Thanks

Comment: how would you change instead of using an article to use a table, im having trouble with it in the newItem function.

Comment: @Patryk1 added a second version (with table)

Comment: yes i can, i was continuing on trying to get the data using the newItem function from the last snippet and trying to parse, wouldnt work. didnt know there are functions to insert cells and rows. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in this line:

```
document.getElementById("chosenFood").value=chosenFood;
```

A [div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) doesn't have a value but you can use the property [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) in order to add something to a div. In any case I assume you wish to add a new paragraph to the inner div, the one with the id **showFoodList**.

In any case I would suggest to use [.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach an event handler to an element.

The fixed code is:

```js
function changeVal()
{
    var f = document.getElementById("food");
    var chosenFood = f.options[f.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("showFoodList").innerHTML += '<p>' + chosenFood + '</p>';
    document.getElementById("chosenFood").className="show";
}
```

```css
.hide{
    display: none;
}
.show{
    display:block;
}
#showFoodList {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <article>
        <h1>List</h1>
        <div>
            <select name="food" id="food" onchange="changeVal()">
                <option value=""selected>Select One</option>
                <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
                <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
                <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
                <option value="All">All Food</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="chosenFood" class="hide">
            <h1 style = "text-align:center;">Food List</h1>
            <div id="showFoodList"></div>
        </div>
    </article>
</main>
```